# What does the "highs" and "lows" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

It's in the  [lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/leave-right-now-lyrics-will-young.html) of Will Young's song-*Leave Right Now*. Part of the lyrics below:

> I'm here so please explain
>   Why you're opening up a healing wound again
>   I'm a little more careful, perhaps it shows
>   *But if I lose the highs at least I'm spared the lows*

So what does "lose the highs" and "spared the lows" possibly mean here?

One explanation is that it means " if I'm not the best then at least I'm not the worst ".  Is that true?

I cannot figure it out. Need help here. Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I lose the highs, at least I'm spared the lows

This means that even if they don't get to experience the great parts, they won't feel the hurt and pain of the bad times. Never having heard the song but glancing at the lyrics, he's likely referring to the ups and downs in a relationship. Though he won't get to experience the joy of being with someone, he won't have to go through the hurt of losing them.